# Wireshark doesnt' recognises RTMP streams

Tags: tcp, streaming, red5, rtmp, wireshark

I found on the web few samples on tracking RTMP *(Real Time Messaging Protocol)* with Wireshark, but it doesn't work for me. All RTMPT packets rendered as basic TCP packet like this:

```
149 14.324999   85.115.xxx.xxx  192.168.1.20    TCP macromedia-fcs > 54557 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1452 Win=69 Len=0
```

I'm using Wireshark 1.2.8 with all protocols installed  on Windows Vista.

What can i do to fix it?

Thx!

Comment: Does RTMPT dissector in wireshark just cover RTMP or does it also have the capability to dissect RTMPS, RTMPE and other FMS protocols?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

WireShark relies on a few heuristics to decide how to decode a stream. One of them is the port number.

The first item to check: is the RTMP using the standard port 1935 in this capture? If not, tell WireShark how to decode it (see last step below).

The second item to check: turn on heuristics *Edit → Preferences → Protocols → TCP → Try heuristic sub-dissectors first*.

If all else fails, brute force: *right-click one of the packets → Decode As... → RTMP*.

Comment: Thanks! It works for most part of packets with second option (Try heuristic sub-dissectors first).

Comment: It does not work well for me - trying to monitor an adaptive rate flash player changing bit rates and can't reliably filter all the control traffic.
The advice provided has helped but not fully resolved the issue
Are there any other tools out there that do work ?